# Why is ffmpeg outputting a 600fps video from a 120fps video input?

Tags: ffmpeg, framerate

I have [a very short 120fps video](https://worm-bucket-prod.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/videos/56bb088118db47954f00006e/cd92b51a-51c6-4580-b86c-e2604cba41f2-720p.mp4).

`ffprobe input.mp4` shows `118.99fps`:

```
ffprobe version 3.0 Copyright (c) 2007-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.29)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.0 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-opencl --enable-libx264 --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libxvid --enable-ffplay --enable-vda
  libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103
  libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102
  libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100
  libavresample   3.  0.  0 /  3.  0.  0
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
[h264 @ 0x7f8262009600] Increasing reorder buffer to 1
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'input.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: mp41mp42isom
    creation_time   : 2016-04-27 10:43:14
  Duration: 00:00:02.76, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 10318 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 720x1280, 10272 kb/s, 118.99 fps, 600 tbr, 600 tbn, 1200 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-04-27 10:43:14
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
```

I'm running a square crop and resize operation:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "crop='if(gte(iw,ih),ih,iw):if(gte(ih,iw),iw,ih)', scale=640x640" -an -c:v libx264 -profile:v high -level 4.1 -preset veryslow -crf 20 output.mp4
```

This gives:

```
....
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'input.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: mp41mp42isom
    creation_time   : 2016-04-27 10:43:14
  Duration: 00:00:02.76, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 10318 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 720x1280, 10272 kb/s, 118.99 fps, 600 tbr, 600 tbn, 1200 tbc (default)
....
Output #0, mp4, to 'output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: mp41mp42isom
    encoder         : Lavf57.25.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 640x640, q=-1--1, 600 fps, 19200 tbn, 600 tbc (default)
....
```

And sure enough, `ffprobe output.mp4` confirms that `output.mp4` is at 600fps, as does VLC.

How can I ensure that ffmpeg will encode my video using the same framerate as the input (be that 30, 60, 120, or 240fps)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**: The PTS entries of the input and output for the command below are identical in version N-79630-g9ac154d. Looks like the file is falsely flagged as VFR. But this single-step command below works for the sample video.

Use

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "crop='if(gte(iw,ih),ih,iw):if(gte(ih,iw),iw,ih)', scale=640x640" \
   -an -c:v libx264 -profile:v high -level 4.1 -preset veryslow -crf 20 -vsync 0 output.mp4
```

---

The framerate stored in the container (`tbr`) is 600, whereas the reported fps of `118.99` is arrived at by counting the number of video packets and dividing by the total duration. If this is not a variable frame rate stream, then add `-r 118.99` as an output option.

---

For older versions,
Alternatively, output to MKV i.e.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "crop='if(gte(iw,ih),ih,iw):if(gte(ih,iw),iw,ih)', scale=640x640" \
   -vsync 0 -an -c:v libx264 -profile:v high -level 4.1 -preset veryslow -crf 20 output.mkv
```

If you then mux the MKV to MP4,

```
ffmpeg -i output.mkv -c copy output.mp4
```

The resulting MP4 will show (close to) the source framerate.

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'no-rc.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.34.103
  Duration: 00:00:02.75, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2462 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x640, 2444 kb/s, 119.88 fps, 600 tbr, 16k tbn (default)
```

Comment: Thanks - the issue with using `-r 118.99` is that the input can be at different framerates. Is there a way to make it dynamic so that `-r <value>` matches the input `fps`?

Comment: Not directly, but yes, if you go through the MKV method as edited.

Comment: Cool workaround - it works. I'm going to leave the question open for a couple of days to see if anyone comes up with a one-step process - if not then I'll accept!

Comment: If there's a bug, please file one at trac.ffmpeg.org ...